# UnifiedJedis' jsonSet consumes nearly 8 times more java heap memory to execute a write operation for a 63 MB JSON data

Tags: java, memory, redis, gson

I am writing a 63.4 MB data file into Redis using UnifiedJedis' jsonSet. I observe that the data size in Redis remains the same, but during this operation, it consumes approximately 499,356 KB (almost 500 MB) of heap memory. Please let me know what will be the correct way to perform this large operation. I am using Jedis 4.4.0-rc1.

```
public static void main(String a[]) {
        HostAndPort config = new HostAndPort("localhost", 6379);
        PooledConnectionProvider pooledConnectionProvider = new PooledConnectionProvider(config);
        try(UnifiedJedis    jedisClient = new UnifiedJedis(pooledConnectionProvider, 10, Duration.ofSeconds(120))) {
            String key = "exampleKey" + System.currentTimeMillis();
            byte[] encoded = java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("C:\\tmp\\flowdata1.txt"));
            jedisClient.jsonSet(key, encoded);
            System.out.println("Data written to Redis successfully!");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
    }
```